# Hide/show div based on form input filed

Tags: jquery, input, show-hide

I have an advanced search div that has 5 form input fields within. This div is hidden by default and it is part of a search form. When a user returns to this page from a results page, I want the div to show assuming any of the 5 fields were populated.

The html is

```
 <a class="toggle-link" onclick="ShowDiv('Adv');">+ show advanced fields</a>

  <div id="Adv" class="slide hidden">
    <form>
     <input type="text" name="first_name">
     <input type="text" name="last_name">
     <input type="text" name="street">
     <input type="text" name="town">
     <input type="text" name="country">
    </form>
    </div>

<a onclick="ShowDiv('Basic');">- hide advanced fields</a>
```

The existing jQuery code that hide / show the divs is:

```
function HideDiv() {
         $('.slide').hide();
     }
     function ShowDiv(ctrl) {
         HideDiv();
         $('#' + ctrl).show();
     }
     ShowDiv('Basic');
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: should you not listen for an event when the input changes and then look if the value.length is 5 ? ans set it to display:block ?

Comment: well, my code doesn't seem to work

Comment: how will you populate the input fields if they are hidden?

Comment: @Sparky672 braces are not required if there is only 1 statement in there

Comment: This div is part of a search form page. The div is hidden by default and I use a toggle anchor link to display for users that want to use advanced search. When a user comes back to this page from a results page, the div is hidden. I want some jQuery code to make sure it displays the div if any of the form input fields were populated

Comment: @Sparky672 You don't need brackets if there's only one function inside the if. I agree on the .val() thing. aa1: seeing the markup would help us help you.

Comment: @Th0rndike and @Muad'Dib, I never knew about that `if/else` shorthand.  Personally, I'd avoid it as to have consistency with the multi-line `if/else` functions.

Comment: Just need the jQuery code that can check if ANY of the 5 input fields were populated in order to show the div when a user returns to the page...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check your form's input elements at page load those are contained in the div (that has id 'Adv') then you should run your check inside document ready event

```
$(function(){
    $("div#Adv input").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()!='')
           $(this).parent().parent().show(); // 1st parent is form, 2nd parent is Adv div 
           return;                       
    });
});
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VBS4E/1/).

This will work only if your any input is populated (contains data) at the time the page is being loaded.

**After your question has been updated I've updated my fiddle** [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VBS4E/3/).

Comment: Thats what I was looking for but doesn't seem to work unfortunately. My page contains data in some of those 5 fields inside the form but the div shows hidden

Comment: the toggle-link I don't think is needed to be changed as it is breaking all together now. I think the first code you submitted without it, it did make sense to me but unfortunately even though the input fields were populated with some values, the div is still hidden....

Comment: I have now edited again my code to show you the exiting jQuery in place that hide/show the div by default. Maybe that's why it does not work with your code you provided?